# jQuery. Call custom function with single $

Tags: jquery

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.test = function () {
        console.log('works');
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    var var1 = $().test(); // works
    var var1 = $.test(); // error: $.test is not a function
});
```

Is it possible to call like this `$.test()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily extend the `jQuery` object itself

```
(function ($) {
    $.test = function () {
        console.log('works');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

But be aware that this function will not be available in `jQuery.fn` (which equals `jQuery.prototype`) and therefore, you can't access `dom nodes` in there via `this`, neither could you *chain* that method after or before other jQuery plugin functions.

The reason why `$().test()` works is, that the jQuery constructor function creates a new object which is linked to `jQuery.fn` (prototype..).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because the jQuery object is actually just the `init` constructor. Meaning that `$` just represents the constructor of a jQuery object. Thus executing `$()` creates an empty jQuery object, which you can then call the prototype method `test()` from.

To access the prototype you can do `$.fn.test();`